Non-linear regression with very noisy data with nls() in R
I am trying to fit noisy data to a specific model with two parameters which I would like to estimate. Unfortunately, the model fit is just terrible with added noise. Is there anything I can do to improve this fit?
The formula/model looks like this:
model_form <- as.formula(y ~ 1/((1/i)-(r*x)))
Below I have created some example how the data looks like. noise is just random additional noise that also occurs in my real dataset (biological origin). Without this noise, the nls() fit works well end estimates r and i good enough. But with the added noise, the model fit and parameter estimation is poor despite visible patterns in the heatmap.
Create sample data with example parameters i and r (these are unknown in reality, but constrained to a specific known interval):
## Create example data
my_i <- 0.5   # example i parameter 
my_r <- 100   # example r parameter
d <- data.frame(x=c(-rexp(500,rate=10),
                    seq(-1,0,length.out = 500))) %>% 
    mutate(y=jitter(1/((1/my_i) - (my_r * x)),1000))
noise <- data.frame(x=runif(1000,-1,0),
                    y=runif(1000,0,0.5))
d <- bind_rows(d,noise)

The following function fits a nls to this data using model_form from above.
fitPlot <- function(data) {
    fit <- nls(model_form,data,
               start=list(r=10,i=0.3))

    fit_r <- summary(fit)$coefficients["r",1]
fit_i <- summary(fit)$coefficients["i",1]

    predicted <- data.frame(x=seq(-1,0,length.out=1000)) %>%
        mutate(y=1 / (1/fit_i - fit_r * x))

    p <- ggplot(data)+
        geom_bin2d(aes(x,y),bins=14)+
        geom_line(data=predicted,aes(x,y))+
        annotate("label",x=-0.7,y=0.5,
                 label=paste0("r: ",fit_r,", i: ",fit_i))
    p
}

fitPlot(d)


Despite the random added noise, the main pattern generated by the function (near 0 and x axis) is still visible in the heat map. That where I would expect a model to fit well.
Is there anything I can do at this point? I have tried

grid search with possible i and r values = same result as nls
optim with different optimization methods, function to minimize SS
nlrob from robustbase with different methods

I am lost at this point, somehow there must be a way to create a robust model? Somehow I need to penalize outliers less, but how? Any help is welcome!

This is really a statistical or optimization question rather than an R coding question. I'm almost certain that nls is giving you the best least-squares fit of this function to these data (so changing starting values won't help, nor will using a different optimizer).

The noise part of your dataset doesn't follow the model that you are fitting.  If you want to fit a model where some data follow a particular functional form, and other data follows a completely different form, there are ways to do that, but they tend not to be very stable or good at identifying the parameters of the functional part of the model.  (Unless you can identify which part of your data is which by some other method, in which case you should just throw away noise.)

@user2554330 Yes noise is the part of the data (example data) that makes the model fit bad. I added noise because my real dataset has some value pairs that don't follow the expected pattern and are just random noise. I've added clarifications to the original post and added a plot to hopefully make the problem clearer.

@leze:  That's fine, but your model needs to also take account of the noise. The nonlinear model you were using doesn't describe the data you are trying to fit.  nls() is designed for the case where the nonlinear expected value function applies to every point and the errors are all additive values from a normal distribution.  That's close enough for the first part of your dataset (the normality assumption isn't crucial), but not at all true for noise.

Okay, thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. How do I account for that error?

The data here is controlled by more that the two parameters you perceive. You will have to do denoising before you estimate the model. The denoising itself is controlled by other parameters.
I will provide a simple denoising process whereby we are interested in a point that is closest to most points around a neighborhood of n points. Here I introduce the parameter $n$ which you need to determine beforehand.
Repeat the process $k$ times until you are satisfied that the data looks okay.  This is a crude way of solving the issue. You could complicate the task by using a criterion to determine the best values for $n$ and $k$
denoise <- function(dat, n, k){
  g <- function(x, n){
    b <- dist(x)
    h <- colSums(as.matrix(`attributes<-`(b<=sort(b)[n], attributes(b))))
    min(as.numeric(names(h)[h>0]))
  }
  
  fn <- function(d, n){
    dat <- d[order(d$x),]
    w <- embed(seq(nrow(dat)), n)
    v <- with(dat, w[cbind(seq(nrow(w)),apply(w, 1, \(u)g(cbind(x[u], y[u]), n%/%2)))]|>
        unique())
    dat[v, ]
  }
  Reduce(\(x,y)fn(x, n),seq_len(k), init = dat)
}

plot(denoise(d, 5, 5))


nls(model_form, denoise(d,5,5),list(r=10,i=0.3))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 1/((1/i) - (r * x))
   data: denoise(d, 5, 5)
      r       i 
81.8277  0.4312 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.923


plot(denoise(d, 20, 3))


nls(model_form, denoise(d,20,3),list(r=10,i=0.3))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 1/((1/i) - (r * x))
   data: denoise(d, 20, 3)
       r        i 
101.2323   0.4871 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.0223

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.247e-06


plot(denoise(d, 10, 5))


nls(model_form, denoise(d,10,5),list(r=10,i=0.3))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 1/((1/i) - (r * x))
   data: denoise(d, 10, 5)
       r        i 
100.9263   0.4835 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.01165

Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.012e-07

